# I need to expand and collapse pure css accordion when I hit keyboard Enter Key for web accessibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I have created an accordion with an input checkbox. No Js used. I need to expand and collapse the accordion when I hit Enter Key in the keyboard. It's for web accessibility. please help me to solve this.

HTML code below

```
<div class="tabs">
        <div class="tab">
          <input type="checkbox" id="chck1" />
          <label class="tab-label" for="chck1">
            Item 1
          </label>
          <div class="tab-content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum, reiciendis!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

CSS code below

```
$midnight: #2c3e50;
$clouds: #ecf0f1;
input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.tab {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  &-label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1em;
    background: $midnight;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  &-content {
    max-height: 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    color: $midnight;
    background: white;
    transition: all .35s;
  }
}
input:checked {
  + .tab-label {
    background: darken($midnight, 10%);
    &::after {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
  }
  ~ .tab-content {
    max-height: 100vh;
    padding: 1em;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### The problem with your current pattern

I know it is frustrating when you ask a simple question of "how do I do this" and someone says "do this instead", but as you have marked this as "accessibility" the way you are implementing this at the moment is problematic.

For example an `<input type="checkbox">` should not exist outside of a `<form>`, so to make your HTML valid you would have to wrap it in a `<form>` element. This then changes the behaviour for a screen reader user as a screen reader would enter "forms mode" which changes the behaviour of the screen reader. There are other reasons such as forms mode expecting <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit something etc. etc.

As you seem to be looking for something that will work without JavaScript (as a fallback....you still need JavaScript to progressively enhance accessibility) may I suggest a much simpler way.

### `<details>` and `<summary>`

It is not often I am able to prescribe a "magic bullet" for a problem, but `<details>` and `<summary>` are actually pretty awesome.

Firstly [support is pretty good](https://caniuse.com/details) and most of the semantics are dealt with automatically for you!

The way to use it is pretty simple, `<details>` is your outer wrapper and this contains the `<summary>` element. The `<summary>` element is effectively your accordion section heading and then you can add anything you want within the `<details>` section below it.

See the following fiddle:

```html
<details>
   <summary>Item 1</summary>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum, reiciendis!</p>
</details>
```

As you can see you get so much baked in functionality. You also get automatic properties such as "expanded / collapsed" announced in most browser / screen reader combinations. Finally in browser that don't support it it just falls back to static content.

### What about Internet Explorer etc?

Now there are a couple of issues with `<details>` and `<summary>`. Internet Explorer does not support it.

This is where we use some JavaScript to improve the accessibility.

If we modify the HTML slightly to include `aria-expanded`, `tabindex="0"` and `role="button"` this fixes the problem. However there is no point doing this for any browser other than IE so I would add it conditionally.

```html
<details>
       <summary role="button" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">Item 1</summary>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum, reiciendis!</p>
    </details>
    <details>
       <summary role="button" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">Item 2</summary>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum, reiciendis!</p>
    </details>
```

You may also want to add `aria-controls` for completeness but I wanted to give you a 99% compatible solution as simply as possible.

Also bear in mind you would need to handle toggling the `aria-expanded` state and actually hiding and showing the content etc.

#### A polyfill I found that may help and a final word on Headings

[Here is a polyfill I found for `<details>` and `<summary>`](http://view-source:https://wet-boew.github.io/wet-boew-documentation/testcase/2018-4.html) that looks pretty good. **I have confirmed it is MIT license so you can use it.**

I would share my own polyfill but it has several dependencies whereas this one is standalone.

**it also appears to deal with a part I left out of discussion so far** - headings. If you use headings (`<h2>` to `<h6>`) to denote each section (depends on page structure whether correct or not) then ideally these should go **around** the `<summary>`.

This is because `<summary>` is treated like a button. However other than headings and section elements nearly everything else can go into the `<summary>` element as it accepts [phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content).

**most of the time I would say it is beneficial to wrap a `<summary>` in an appropriate level `<h2>` to `<h6>` due to how screen reader users navigate, but it is not a requirement. **

### Styling etc.

A final thing that might not be immediately apparent. If you want to apply styling based on the current start (expanded / closed) it exposes an attribute `open` when expanded.

`<details open>` (expanded) vs `<details>` (closed).

You can use this for CSS selectors with `details['open']` to style the container and `details[open]>summary` to style the summary.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    document.getElementById("#chck1").checked = true
  }
});
```

Comment: bad idea , why would you attach `Enter` to just a certain html element